# How to list wine processes on the terminal screen?

Tags: process, wine

I'm aware that I can run Task Manager by: `wine taskmgr`. However I'd like to have wine processes listed on the terminal screen similar to `ps` (but without using it), but for processes within Wine environment only.

How this can be achieved using Wine command-line tools?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found that this can be listed by using `winedbg` command, e.g.

```
winedbg --command "info proc"
```

> Use the `info proc` winedbg command to list running processes and their Win32 pids.

See: [`man winedbg`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/winedbg).